# Can a Discord Bot Invite Other Bots?

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.py

Can a Discord bot invite other bots? Can Discord bots automatically  accept invites they get in a DM? How would one go about doing this?

Is it possible to make a bot that accepts invites, or do bots have to be invited themselves.

Comment: Btw Thanks In Advance... :)

Comment: I *don't think* it's possible. Each bot's entry has to be user authenticated through the invite link

Comment: hmm i cant to do it then i guess btw thanks for replying

Comment: Nope! it's absolutely impossible since all bots need to be authenticated through their Oauth links

Comment: And it's good, that this is not possible. Just imagine...you could create big chains of bots who can spam multiple servers

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

Users must invite the bot themselves to join the server. I'm not sure I understand the use case here, because users can get similar functionality by simply inviting the bot.

To generate an invite link, start by heading to the [Discord developer portal.](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

Then, head to the "OAuth2" tab:

[image]

Scroll down and find the URL generator. You'll need to select the following:

[image]

[image]

Generally you'll want to calculate the permissions, but this will work for now.

Now, if you want users to invite your bot, you just need to share them this link!